# How to set the ios 5 HTML5 input of type="date" to the current date & time?

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I tried the obvious and does not work...

```
var dtel = document.getElementById("element-id");
dtel.value = new Date();
```

It needs a string but what is the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many trials and errors I found that the following works:

```
var dtel = document.getElementById("element-id");
var dt = new Date();
dtel.value = dt.toISOString();
```